# Does SQL Server place shared locks on scanned records when using REPEATABLE READ

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, locking, transaction, isolation-level

Assume a `SQLCmd` session which is using transaction isolation level `REPEATABLE READ`.

In this session I start a transaction and execute an `UPDATE` statement with a `WHERE` clause on  a non indexed column. This statement should evaluate `WHERE` clause for each record in the table, but only one will match.

If I examine the locks placed under this transaction after running the `UPDATE` statement I can only see two `IX` locks on Table and Page, and a `X` lock on the row which was updated.

My question is: shouldn't the database engine place shared locks on all the rows it read to ensure `REPEATABLE READ`? What if some other transaction updates a record so that it would match with my WHERE clause in the UPDATE statement, thereby violating the `REPEATABLE READ`.

If I execute a `SELECT *`, then I can see it placing `S` locks on each row, which are not already locked with `X`.

Can anyone help me understand this situation?

I've tried with both SQL Server 2008 R2 and 2012, same behavior in both.